# How to write xpath?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have difficulty to develop x path for below code:

```
<div class="checkbox-detailed">
<input type="radio" name="service_id" id="service-translation" data-text="translation" class="service_id edit-radio" value="1">
<label for="service-translation">
<<pseudo:before>>
</<pseudo:before>>
<span class="checkbox-detailed-tbl">
<span class="checkbox-detailed-cell">
<span class="checkbox-detailed-title">Translation</span>
```

Comment: What element are you trying to identify? What have you tried? What is your difficulty?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='service-translation']")).click();

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='checkbox-detailed']/input[@id='service-translation']/label[@for='service-translation']"))

Comment: I have share my code.I have tried using id